# A brand new installation of tex4ebook gives an attempt to index nil error

Tags: tex4ebook

I am trying tex4ebook for the first time. After following the installation instructions in:
https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook/blob/master/INSTALL.md

I get the following error:

```
(pipeline) tania@maltserver:/mnt/hdd/tania/monograph$ tex4ebook --version
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/mkutils.lua:3: attempt to index a nil value (global 'logging')
```

Platform is Ubuntu 20.04.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You should not need to follow those instructions, tex4ebook is part of texlive. If you install mismatched versions then errors like this may occur.  did you re-install all of tex4ht or are you using your ubuntu tex4ht with tex4book additions from github?

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I reinstalled all of tex4ht. 
I just installed texlive-full on another server and verified that the tex4ebook does not give this error.

Comment: You should be able to install a compatible tex4ht via apt `apt get texlive-full` or some smaller subset